# Conditional form in the status related sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions

The following sentence belongs to which conditional form:

> If you are speaking a lot some particular language, you are in love
> with that language.

As per my knowledge, we use present/past simple/perfect with the "If" part. So I am not clear about this form of conditional sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbered conditionals usually taught are:

0. The zero conditional (which judging by its name must have been added as an afterthought) - simple present in both clauses.
1. The first conditional - simple present in the subordinate clause, a future construction ("will" or "shall" +bare infinitive) in the main clause.
2. The second conditional - simple past in the subordinate clause, a conditional construction ("would"+bare infinitive) in the main clause.
3. The third conditional - past perfect in the subordinate clause, a conditional perfect ("would have"+past participle) in the main clause.

However, sometimes we use the present progressive in (0) and (1), or the past progressive in (2).  For example:

- If I were eating a doughnut right now, I would be happier.

To my mind, the above is still a valid second conditional, even though it doesn't fit the canonical pattern (since the subordinate clause uses a progressive construction instead of the simple past).

Similarly, "If you're speaking a particular language a lot, you are in love with that language" strikes me as a variation on the "zero conditional".

Ultimately, whether this is a zero conditional or not depends on the particular framework you're using and the precise definitions you choose to adopt.

It is well known that not all conditional sentences used by native speakers fit into one of the numbered conditional patterns.  The numbered conditionals are just a learning aid, not an exhaustive list of grammatically possible conditionals.